# Deleting the second item from a search in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

A friend of mine found this in a test, and I am puzzled by it. Not using cursors, nor distinct, neither sub-selects, it is possible to delete the second **code '2'** in a table that looks like this? *(Preferably with a single statement)*

```
code  |  Name
--------------
   1  |  Name1
   2  |  Name2
   3  |  Name3
   1  |  Name1
   1  |  Name1
   2  |  Name2     <----delete this field
   3  |  Name3
```

Comment: As written, the question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  Data in a heap organized table is inherently unordered.  The only way to reasonably talk about the "first" or "second" or "last" row is after applying an `ORDER BY`.  But there doesn't appear to be any obvious way to order the data in this table to ensure that the specified row is the "second" row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the result set, you might point to something and say "second row", but technically there is no such "guaranteed" second row. You need to be able to order your result set in a specific order (usually per requirement) and then identify the second row.

So, a question like this, instead, would have a definitive answer.

Delete the second "code 2" from the table ***when data is ordered by name ascending***. (Even in this case, there is the question of what to do when there are multiple rows with code 2 and the same name)

--identify the row to be deleted.

```
select rowid from (
  select rowid, 
         rank () over (order by name asc) rnk --or dense_rank 
                                              --depending on requirement
  from   test_table
  where  code = 2
)where rnk = 2
```

--delete the row, using the selected rowid.

```
delete from test_table
where rowid in (
 <query above..>
};
```